# How do I set weight painting brushes to limit total vertex weight to 1?

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-weights

I'm using Blender 2.8!
I was wondering if there any way to set the weight brush so that if a bone controls a point (or group of points) with a strength of 1, it will automatically remove the strength influence on the point from other bones to 0?

In my line of work, no point should ever have a weight value more than 1. So things like two bones affecting a point with a strength of 1 should never happen.

I keep seeing this nightmare on tutorials where they have to guess which bone is affecting their vertexes and manually remove the influence from all other bones aside from the one they want to controlling the vertexes.

I was just wondering if there was another way. 
Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The auto-normalise setting in the brush menu will make it so the total weights on any vertex that you paint are adjusted to sum to 1. This has bee in blender for a long time, see https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/painting/weight_paint/tools.html.

The menu options is here in 2.8:
[image]

Comment: Thank you!!! Wow, I swear none of the tutorials on YouTube went over that. Much appreciated!

Comment: @GoodNight click the tick button next to the answer to show that this solved your problem.

Comment: Oh! Ok, did it!